# Fish shell doesn't return program error

Tags: shell, fish

In bash, if I run a program and it crashes I get some information about what went wrong, such as `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. In fish, I just get `fish:` but no message... does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: Works for me: "`sleep 888 &`" then "`kill -11 %1`" produces "`fish: Job 1, 'sleep 888 &' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)`". What does `fish -v` report? What does `locale` output and if it isn't english does the problem go away if you switch to an english, or `POSIX` locale?

Comment: Hmmm, that works for me to (gives the same return you have). It's when I run C code I've written myself. I'll write up a MWE tomorrow.
`fish -v` gives `2.6.0`, and `locale` doesn't specify a `LANG` or `LC_ALL`. `LC_CTYPE` is `UTF-8` and the rest is `C`

Answer (score 0):

Im not familiar with fish as a shell, but upon quick googleing fu, https://fishshell.com/docs/current/
section: Input/Output (IO) redirection and https://fishshell.com/docs/current/faq.html question: How do I get the exit status of a command?

Are these errors printed or redirected correctly or captured in any way? By default, are they set to be printed to your default screen? some results suggest updating to the latest version, I guess that means checking if your versions is either outdated or having an isue. Getting either the latest or latest stable one availeble for your distro or from Github might help.